Do a where comparaison on geo_point data with ODSQL
I'm trying to analyze data from this ODWB dataset before accessing it.
I can filter by stop name using WHERE stop_name = 'city', but I'm getting too many responses.
I want to narrow down the results by looking for stops within a specific geographical area, defined by minimum and maximum latitude and longitude. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this in ODSQL.
Here's an example of the structure of the stop_coordinates field:
"stop_coordinates": {
"lon": 3.253948,
"lat": 50.710683
}
I've tried a few different approaches, but none seem to work:
Using ->> operator:
WHERE stop_coordinates ->> 'lat' >= 'MIN_LATITUDE'
  AND stop_coordinates ->> 'lat' <= 'MAX_LATITUDE'
  AND stop_coordinates ->> 'lon' >= 'MIN_LONGITUDE'
  AND stop_coordinates ->> 'lon' <= 'MAX_LONGITUDE'

Directly accessing latitude and longitude fields:
WHERE stop_coordinates.latitude BETWEEN MIN_LATITUDE AND MAX_LATITUDE
  AND stop_coordinates.longitude BETWEEN MIN_LONGITUDE AND MAX_LONGITUDE;

However, both of these approaches result in an error like:
Incompatible types in comparison filter. Left type: geo_point_2d, right_type: geo_point_2d. Clause(s) containing the error(s): where.
Does anyone know the correct syntax or approach to filter by latitude and longitude coordinates in ODSQL? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
